# how to use String[] args when using re-direction (">>") in c#?

Tags: c#, debugging, redirect, command-line-arguments

I have a program test.exe that receives arguments and writes some logs in a specific .txt path that I give as an input.
I wanted to add this command:

```
text.exe /r >> textFile.txt
```

meaning : build the project and write the logs to the textFile.txt (that doesn't exist)
I'm not sure how it works? is `args[2] = ">>"` and `args[3] = textFile.txt` ?
how can I use the name of it??
confused!

editing :
when I'm debugging and looking at the locals I see only `/r` but the `>> textFile.txt` doesn't appear at all.
how can I get it fro the command line as a pararmeter?

edit2 :

Understood that it should re-direct automatically, but when I'm doing it it just fails and sends me to a line : `Console.CursorLeft = 0;` meaning i'm trying to do somethong with the cursor when I don't have a console... just .txt

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the command shell will *only* pass `/r` to `test.exe`, and it will automatically redirect output to append to `textFile.txt`. Your app doesn't get to see that - at least not simply.

If you just make your program write to the standard output (e.g. with `Console.WriteLine`) that output will end up in `textFile.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

">>" is used by the Command prompt as a special command to tell it to redirect output to the following file.

You do not need to handle this in your program; just do your normal `Console.WriteLine()` calls, and the output will be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application in command prompt and the pass parameters like:

```
c:\>test.exe /r >> textFile.txt
```

the command prompt understands that it need to pass only the parameter /r to our program the file name after >> is for his usage.
e.g try running following command in your command prompt

```
c:\>ipconfig
```

and

```
c:\>ipconfig >> text.txt
c:\>notepad.exe text.txt
```

you will find for first  time  output is shown on screen and the second time it was written in file name you gave by command prompt itself.